# getCollection()->getSize() not returning correct number of records

Tags: collection, products, product-collection, varien

getCollection()->getSize() not returning correct number of records.

Here is my code

```
:

        /** @var $collection Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_inventory_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('vendor')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('cost')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('inventory_category')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('inventory_position')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('min_order_qty')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
            ->filterByIsQtyProductTypes()
            ->joinInventoryItem('qty')
            ->useManageStockFilter($storeId)
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                                    array(
                                          array('attribute'=>'vendor', 'finset'=>$this->getFilter('vendor'))
                                    )
                                );

        if( $storeId ) {
            $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("(min_qty - qty) as order_qty"));
        $collection->getSelect()->having('order_qty > 0');

        $collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('inventory_category', 'ASC');
        $collection->getSelect()->order('CAST(`inventory_position` AS SIGNED) ASC');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
```

Then in my .phtml file:

```
echo $this->__('Total %d records found', $this->getCollection()->getSize())
```

`getSize()` is returning the number of records before I add this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("(min_qty - qty) as order_qty"));
$collection->getSelect()->having('order_qty > 0');
```